# How to write POST HTTR request for Spotify API

Tags: r, api, post, spotify, httr

I am trying to create a playlist on my Spotify in R via HTTR and the Spotify API. I can't quite figure out how to structure the POST request however.

This is the POST request I am using in R 

    `HeaderValue = "Authorization Code"
    n = "application/json"
    response = POST(
      'https://open.spotify.com/v1/users/(myuserid)/playlists',
     accept_json(),
     add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue, "Content-Type" = n),
     body = list(name = "New Playlist1", public = "true"),
     encode = 'form',
     verbose()
    )`

This is what the request SHOULD look like from the Spotify API website: 

    `POST /v1/users/121616946/playlists HTTP/1.1
    Host: api.spotify.com
    Content-Length: 40
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
   Accept: application/json
   User-Agent: Spotify API Console v0.1
   Content-Type: application/json
   Authorization: "Authorization Code"
   {"name": "New Playlist", "public": true}enter code here`

This is what I get in the R Console

`POST /v1/users/121616946/playlists HTTP/1.1
    Host: open.spotify.com
    User-Agent: libcurl/7.43.0 r-curl/1.2 httr/1.2.1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept: application/json
    Authorization: "Authorization Code"
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 32
    name=New%20Playlist1&public=true
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    Server: nginx
    Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 19:57:41 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
     Connection: keep-alive
     Keep-Alive: timeout=10
     Vary: Accept-Encoding
     Cache-Control: no-cache
     Content-Encoding: gzip`

Tl;Dr: I think my issue is the body of the POST. I don't think I'm formatting it correctly in the call. I may be missing something else though, but I'm not sure what. The Authorization token is fully authorized to do what I am asking it do as well, so that will not be an issue.

Comment: _"404 Not Found"_ - from the error message I'd assume there is no url `https://open.spotify.com/v1/users/121616946/playlists` (?). Do you have a links to the api documentation? Have you verified the url exists?

Comment: Luke is correct. It is not open.spotify.com. The [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/create-playlist/) - says `POST https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists`

Comment: You are correct guys. That was a stupid oversight on my part. I also had to change the encode = form to encode = json. Works now. Thanks again!